# shows define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true)) - when i migrate php version to 7.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, php-7.3

I got following Message(Access Home Page of Applications) when I update my Development Environment to PHP 7.3

```
*/ 

  define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true)); 

/* 
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
| Turn On The Lights 
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
| 
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights. 
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send 
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users. 
| 
*/ 

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php'; 

/* 
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
| Run The Application 
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
| 
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request 
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to 
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative 
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them. 
| 
*/ 

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class); 
$response = $kernel->handle( $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture() ); 
$response->send(); 
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

How to handle this?

Comment: What message? The code? I don't understand

Comment: The snippet you posted does not contain a PHP opening tag `<?php`. Is it possible you accidentally removed it?

Answer (score 1):

Some part of the script is missing, but it seems that your php files are treated like text! Check your server settings after upgrading to php 7.3. I guess that the problem is with any php script

Answer (score 1):

Its a PHP 7.3 Installation Issue. I reinstalled it has been fixed.

Comment: Glad to see this solution, I told you earlier If you're seeing code in the browser, **you don't have PHP installed correctly**

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing code in the browser, you don't have PHP installed correctly

You can check PHP version is installed or not in your local computer using the Command Prompt `php -v`

Comment: PHP 7.3.3-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Mar  7 2019 20:48:45) ( NTS )

Answer (score 0):

I think apache2 is not setup properly with PHP

Try again
`sudo apt-get install php7.4/php7.3`

Answer (score 0):

i faced this problem after installing ALPN and Http2/protocol to my server!

for handling this problem do this:

> ps:  i'm using **direct admin** for my host, this process can be
> different in other host manager like **cpanel** or **plesk**, but
> surely all of them will have the same capability.

**go to host of your domain(not the root)->Domain Setup->click on your domain(example.com)->Php settings->increase your memory limit (to 512M for example)->click on save button in front of memory_limit->check your site after 2 minutes**