# After upgrading to Ubunto 19.10 does my Laravel app not load?

Tags: linux, laravel, apache, ubuntu

After upgrading my remote Ubuntu server to 19.10 my site/app no longer loads and I see the page below in the browser window. Why would that be? Thanks

[image]

Comment: It's possible PHP isn't loading page correctly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55487812/shows-definelaravel-start-microtimetrue-when-i-migrate-php-version-to-7

Comment: install and enable php apache module

Comment: I think this question helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page

Comment: what web server are you using? Apache or nginx?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like upgrading Ubuntu had updated Apache and probably changed some config files. I reinstalled PHP and the PHP MySQL module and the site is now back up.